# HTML button only works when cursor over top border

Tags: html, css

I have a button

```
<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search Table'>
```

[image: button]

It does not work unless the cursor pointer is on the top border. I highlighted it in red. It's also the same for the input field on the left.

I can enter text unless I click on the top border of field.

Never came across this before.

Comment: Check the z-index of this element. Maybe there is another element on top of it.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I changed the z-index as there was an element set at 30. But I also have a sort button and now that doesn't work and I set its z-index to 100

Comment: By inspecting the elements you should be able to see what's going on. You most likely have an issue with elements covering other elements.

Comment: @HanletEscaño correct, never set width of the divs and they were overlapping. Thanks fixed now!